# HTMLElement.click() would not fire an expected event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script-editor

I try to use some simple native javascript code, in order to simulate a user click on a button at script.google.com:

```
document.querySelector("#runButton").click();
```

When I do it, nothing really happens, but when I really click on this element (`#runButton`), I can see a popup shows up.

It might have something to do with the fact that `#runButton` is a div,
 cause when I do the same with anchor() elements, it works.

Any ideas what I can do to better simulate this click? Something specific about google apps script editor that prevents me from doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Google Apps Script editor supresses programmatic `click` events on interface buttons, here is solution to emulate "click" on those buttons:

```
function doClick(n)
{
    e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");  
    e.initEvent("mousedown", true, false);  
    n.dispatchEvent(e,true); 
    e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");  
    e.initEvent("mouseup", true, false);  
    n.dispatchEvent(e,true);
}

// do the click
doClick(document.getElementById("runButton"));
```

Comment: But you should know that createEvent is being deprecated and may stop working at any moment. Which happened in my case.